# Regex part of URL string

Tags: regex

I have the following strings

```
https://test.com/fi/wp-content
https://test.com/fr
https://test.com/es
https://test.com/
https://test.com/wp-content/
https://test.com/image.png
https://test.com/de/wp-content/themes
https://test.com/es
https://test.com/fr
https://test.com/no
https://test.com/da
https://test.com/en
https://test.com/de
https://test.com/nl/wp-content
https://test.com/fi
```

As far as now I have the following regex

```
/\btest.com.*\.*(?<!fr|es|da|no|en|de|nl|fi)$/gm
```

I want to match the following (image 1)
[image]

Im almost there but my regex matches everything after my expression like this (image 2):
[image]

I can seem to figure out how to get the end of my regex to behave so it produces the match as image 1.
Here is a regex101: https://regex101.com/r/Tv0AjJ/1

Comment: It should be like this `\btest\.com\/(?!fr|es|d[ae]|no|en|nl|fi)` https://regex101.com/r/P5dgv8/1

Comment: `/(?<=https?://)([^/]+)/)/`

Comment: It should actually be `\btest\.com\/(?!(?:fr|es|da|no|en|de|nl|fi)\/)` or even `\btest\.com\/(?!(?:fr|es|da|no|en|de|nl|fi)(?:\/|$))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently this part `.*(?<!fr|es|da|no|en|de|nl|fi)$` matches until the end of the string and asserts what is to the left is not any of the alternatives, that is why `/es` does not match but `.png` does.

You can match the `/` and then assert not any of the alternatives directly to the right using a negative lookahead `(?!`

Note to escape the the dot.

```
\btest\.com\/(?!fr|es|d[ae]|no|en|nl|fi)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/P5dgv8/1)

If you don't want partial matches, you can either group the alternatives themselves again follwed by a word boundary `\b` or as Wiktor Stribiżew
mentioned in the comments a forward slash or the end of the string `(?:\/|$)`

Alternatives that have the same character can be grouped together in a character class `d[ae]`

```
\btest\.com\/(?!(?:fr|es|d[ae]|no|en|nl|fi)\b)
```